# May modal verbs get discerned intransitive?

Tags: modal-verbs, transitivity

> I will.

*will*, modal verb, *I*, subject. May modal verbs get discerned intransitive? May they get discerned intransitive, this may seem a complete sentence and not request an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full modal verbs (*can/could*, *may/might*, *must*, *shall/should*, *will/would*) never occur except with the bare infinitive of a lexical verb as complement.

The only circumstance in which *I will* could be a grammatically complete sentence is if the complement of *will* is implied by the preceding discourse:

> "Will you see Jack tonight?" "I will [*<s>see Jack tonight</s>*]."

There is also a different verb, lexical *will*; the two are historically related, but unlike modal *will*, lexical *will* is conjugated regularly (*He wills*, *He willed*) in its finite forms and has regular non-finite forms (*He has willed*, *He is willing*, *He wants to will*). Lexical *will*  is transitive, requiring an object.

Comment: I thank you. I may not get *full* in *full modal verbs*. I think I may get that *I will ([full?] modal verb[?]* may not get discerned  a complete sentence. That there maybe seems two *wills* may seem new to me. I guess I thought *will* mostly like "choose", "choose to". I may not get lexical verbs. I do like this. There may seem different verbs, lexical(?), modal(?), dynamic(?), I may not get all of them and why there may seem different verbs. Mostly I do get *I will*  may not get discerned a complete sentence. So I guess I think modal verb *will* like transitive. I thank you, StoneyB.